# How to release a key in postmessage

Tags: c#, keyboard, hook, mouse

I wrote a game program that sends events to another window, but I have such a problem - it doesn't let go of the keys. How can I fix it?

thanks in advance
code:

```
 const uint WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
    const uint WM_KEYUP = 0x0101;

    const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
    const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;


        Process[] processList = Process.GetProcesses();

        int Okrazenia = Convert.ToInt32(OkrazeniaCheck.Text);
        int Tury = 999999;

        foreach (Process P in processList)
        {
            if (P.ProcessName.Equals(processName))
            {
                IntPtr edit = P.MainWindowHandle;

                for (int i = 0; i < Tury; i++)
                {
                    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < Okrazenia; i2++)
                    {
                        PostMessage(edit, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, (IntPtr)(Keys.LButton), IntPtr.Zero);
                        Thread.Sleep(10);
                        PostMessage(edit, WM_KEYDOWN, (IntPtr)(Keys.W), IntPtr.Zero);
                        Thread.Sleep(Convert.ToInt32(przod.Text));
                        PostMessage(edit, WM_KEYUP, (IntPtr)(Keys.W), IntPtr.Zero);
                        Thread.Sleep(10);
```

Comment: I want the ** KEY_UP ** key to be released

Comment: It's probably much easier (and more likely to work), if you use the AutomationAPI https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/ui-automation-specification , which is for exactly this purpose.